# VB.net Coded PictureBox not a member from Form1

Tags: vb.net

I have two Forms, Form1 has a clickable picturebox created object through code, when it click it will show Form2. Form2, I have a button, when it click it will set image and display into picturebox from Form1.

**FORM1:**

```
Dim pbLogo As New PictureBox
pbLogo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
pbLogo.Visible = True
pbLogo.Size = New Size(202, 86)
pbLogo.Location = New Point(29, 23)
AddHandler pbLogo.Click, AddressOf PictureBox_Click
Me.Controls.Add(pbLogo)
```

**PictureBox_Click**

```
Private Sub PictureBox_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)                     
    FORM2.Show()
End Sub
```

Problem is I can't access the Picturebox object to set image and display. It says

> pbLogo is not a member of Form1

which is obvious because it is not running yet.

**FORM2**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Hide()
    Form1.pbLogo.image = Application.StartupPath + "\images\logo.jpg"
End Sub
```

I can achieve it if pbLogo picturebox object exist in Form1 and access it in Form2. For me, not good idea if I have lots of picturebox created in Form1 but can be achieve.

I want to test single picturebox first and if succeed then I will proceed to array of picturebox.

Any help very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in Form1 (first sample) is inside a sub.

pbLogo is only visible in the sub it is dimm'd. (this is called Variable Scoping)

Take this line of code OUT of the sub:

```
Dim pbLogo As New PictureBox
```

and put it at the top of the file - 'class scope' so to say.

Write it like this:

```
public pbLogo As New PictureBox
```

You should be able to see it from the other form.

(note, VB really lets you do an ugly thing when you say 'form1.pblogo' and it works. But it works. Because vb is doing some things behind the scenes. Better to pass around an instance of the actual form1 object. But if it works, I would say, you can grow old trying to be perfect. Unless you have some snobs reviewing your code ;-)

Comment: I guess the question then becomes, if you're declaring the variable at the class level and creating it where it's declared, why not just add it in the designer? If the answer is that the idea is to be able to add multiple `PictureBox` controls then your code won't work as is because you'd need a collection.

Comment: @funkomz thanks - remember to click the checkmark by the answer I get 10 points or something like that. (I think I should get a couple pieces of crisp bacon, but hey, I don't run StackOverflow, I'll settle for the points).